# cv2 face recognition CascadeClassifier() takes no arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have this TypeError: CascadeClassifier() takes no arguments in my python code. can anyone help me to solve it?

i want it to identify a face.

Comment: Please paste your code in the question and please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.